# Detect jQuery accordion closed status

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a piece of code that would allow me to detect if the accordion section is closed (with jquery)?

```
if (accordion is closed) {
    // DO THIS
}
```

Comment: If there's a class that gets added to the accordion element you could check for the class. `$(element).hasClass('accordionClosed')`

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( !$('#accordion div#section_id').hasClass('ui-accordion-content-active') ) {
    // DO THIS
}
```

The class ui-accordion-content-active is applied to the active accordion section. If it doesn't have this class it's closed.

Answer (score 0):

With the default setup of [jQuery UI Accordion widget](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/) -
there is a `ui-accordion-content-active` class that is added to open sections.

You can use it:

```
if(!$panel.is(".ui-accordion-content-active")){
   // DO STUFF
}
$activePanel = $(".ui-accordion-content.ui-accordion-content-active");
$closedPanels = $(".ui-accordion-content:not(.ui-accordion-content-active)");
```